# How to link effects to mouse direction

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add visual effects to a website, and I've come across [this](http://baumbastisch.com/) amazing effect : the color overlays are sliding in the direction of the mouse (if it's coming from the right so will the overlay..)

I have absolutely no idea how to do this, so I'm not asking you to detail this effect entirely but just, if you could, explain in general how to affect the effects by a movement of the mouse?

Another example of the kind of effect I'm talking about would be [this one](http://cuberto.com/).

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Isn't it one example of those never-do effects, like background flashing in HTML1?

Answer (score 1):

Source article about it: [LINK](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/)

Gitlab JS solution: [LINK](https://github.com/codrops/DirectionAwareHoverEffect)

So basically if you have structure, from article:

```
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
    <li>
        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/502538-Natalie-Justin-Cleaning">
            <img src="images/7.jpg" />
            <div><span>Natalie & Justin Cleaning by Justin Younger</span></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

you should use CSS:

```
.da-thumbs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.da-thumbs li a,
.da-thumbs li a img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.da-thumbs li a {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then pass at jQuery (include before a github package (link above): hoverdir):

```
$('#da-thumbs > li').hoverdir();
```

It will do for you everything :)

Comment: You have it all at this tutorial page...
This tutorial is to achieve : https://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/

Comment: That's the point. What if the link dies? See this [post on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Aaahhh ok. I will update my answer within seconds :)

Comment: Yes, I agree... So, my changed message right now is correct, yes? :)